# Classifiers not working in logistic regression model

Tags: python

I am trying to fit a Logistic Regression model to some images, and 10 classifiers.

The images are stored in folders that correspond to the class names (class0, class1, ... , class9). I also have a csv which contains the classifier and filename of the image.

My script is as follows:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
from keras.utils import np_utils
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageEnhance

data = pd.read_csv('folder/images.csv')
## this includes columns such as the classnames (classname) and image name (e.g., 1111.jpg)


class_labels = {'c0': 'Class0', 
                'c1': 'Class1', 
                'c2': 'Class2', 
                'c3': 'Class3', 
                'c4': 'Class4', 
                'c5': 'Class5', 
                'c6': 'Class6', 
                'c7': 'Class7', 
                'c8': 'Class8', 
                'c9': 'Class9'}

classes = data.groupby( [ 'classname'] ).size().to_frame(name = 'count').reset_index()
classes['Classlabel'] = list(class_labels.values())
ClassNames = classes['classname'].to_numpy()
ClassCount = len(ClassNames)

train_path = "folder/imgs/train"

x_train_all = [] 
y_train_all = []

input_image = (64,64)

def load_image(path):
    read_path = train_path+"/"+path
    image = Image.open(read_path)
    image = image.resize(input_image)

    return np.asarray(image)

split_rate = 0.9 # split training and validation
for current_class in ClassNames:
    select_df = data[data['classname'] == current_class ]
    image_list = select_df['img'].values
    train_amount = int(len(image_list)*split_rate)
    train_all_list = image_list[:]

    for filename in train_all_list:
        x_train_all.append(load_image(current_class+"/"+filename))
        y_train_all.append(current_class.replace('c',''))
    

x_train_all = np.asarray(x_train_all)
y_train_all =tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train_all, num_classes=ClassCount)


#reshape
x_train_all_count, x_train_all_width, x_train_all_height, x_train_all_channel = x_train_all.shape
d2_x_train_all = x_train_all.reshape((x_train_all_count,x_train_all_width*x_train_all_height*x_train_all_channel))

y_train_1_col = y_train_all[:, [1]]
y_train_1_col

LR_X_train, LR_X_test, LR_y_train, LR_y_test = train_test_split(d2_x_train_all, y_train_1_col, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

model_LogRegr = LogisticRegression(max_iter=10000).fit(LR_X_train, LR_y_train.ravel())

y_pred = model_LogRegr.predict(LR_X_test)
print('Accuracy: {:.2f}'.format(model_LogRegr.score(LR_X_test, LR_y_test)))


confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(LR_y_test, y_pred)
print(confusion_matrix)
```

I believe there is something going wrong as my confusion matrix is a 2x2 grid - but as I have 10 classifiers, it should be a 10x10 grid.

Why hasn't my model accepted the classifiers originally identified in the classname column of the csv file?

Comment: Your example is too long and too specific for help. Can you make a more minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: I thought I had made it reproducible by providing all steps it take me to get to the point of producing the confusion matrix (plus, I don't know where within the process I'm losing my 10 classifiers) - so I'm not sure how I would slim this down. All I could do more is provide the a sample csv file and sample images - but this is going to be fairly superficial as there are lots of images, which is why I tried to explain as much as I could about how the data is stored, i.e. the csv and the images in folders